# how do I use await with map and forEach?

Tags: dictionary, asynchronous, typescript, async-await

I'm trying to process an array of items, and need to use an async function within the block. I need to make the outer loop some type of `async` function so I can use `await` within the loop.

But I can't seem to make the loop 'await' before continuing.
The code below just prints out `msgs` as `[]` and then runs through the loop.

```
// with a foreach 
      let msgs = [];
      items.forEach(function(item, index) {
        item.laws.forEach(async function(law) {
          let orig = await Laws.coll.findOne({url: law.cname});
          let title = Laws.title(orig);
          let msg = `<${law.cname}|${title}>`;
          msgs.push(msg);
          debug("title", title, msg);
        });
      });

      debug("msgs", msgs); // => shows []
```

and I also tried various syntax with `map`

```
  items.map(await async function(item) {
    item.laws.map(await async function(law) {
      let orig = await Laws.coll.findOne({url: law.cname});
      let title = Laws.title(orig);
      let msg = `<${law.cname}|${title}>`;
      msgs.push(msg);
      debug("title", title, msg);
    });
  });
```

FWIW I tried:

```
await item.laws.map(async function() ...
//and
item.laws.map(await async function() ...
```

without success.

In both cases the loop runs *after* the `debug("msgs", msgs)` has printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve the problem.

1. Use `for(let of items){...}` instead
2. Made promise sequences as described in [Javascript Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) -> Creating a sequence

The reason is both map and forEach calls the provided callback but do not wait for it to be executed.

Comment: thanks for this! I now have another tool to use with await :)